# How to loop through getElementsByClass for image expansion

Tags: javascript, image, for-loop, dom, image-enlarge

The for loop is not working to expand the image.

When I place an index at the end, it works. So I know indirectly that there is nothing wrong with HTML and CSS, and that the function works.

```
const expandImage = document.getElementsByClassName('website_image')[0];

expandImage.addEventListener('mouseover', expand);

function expand(event){
  expandImage.style.padding='11%';
}
```

However, when I attempt to do a for loop:

```
const expandImage = document.getElementsByClassName('website_image');

for(let i=0; i<expandImage.length; i++) {

expandImage.addEventListener('mouseover', expand);

function expand(event){
  expandImage.style.padding='11%';
}
}
```

Nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `expandImage[i]` to reference an element

Comment: Don't use an external reference to the hovered element. Instead, retrieve the element from the event object: `event.target.style ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not referencing the array element in your loop, you're referencing the whole array. You need to use the equivalent of `[0]` inside your loop, in this case, `[i]`.

```
const expandImage = document.getElementsByClassName('website_image');

for(let i=0; i<expandImage.length; i++) {

expandImage[i].addEventListener('mouseover', expand);

function expand(event){
  expandImage[i].style.padding='11%';
}
}
```

But you'll find this won't work either! You can't access `expandImage[i]` within your function because by the time it executes, `i` is equal to `expandImage.length`. You'll need to store a reference in the declaring scope for the current element of `expandImage`, or it might be simpler to just use the `this` object in your method:

```
const expandImage = document.getElementsByClassName('website_image');

for(let i=0; i<expandImage.length; i++) {

expandImage[i].addEventListener('mouseover', expand);

function expand(event){
  this.style.padding='11%';
}
}
```

Comment: Are you come from Israel?

Comment: No, I'm from Australia.

Comment: Sorry for that,because I usually see the name `benjamin netanyahu`

Answer (score 0):

Use `expandImage[i]` not as `expandImage`